# Read array from .txt data

Tags: arrays, io, fortran

I would like to read an array from a .txt file in Fortran. I tried it with the following code:

```
PROGRAM test_performance
IMPLICIT NONE
DOUBLE PRECISION, DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE :: ARRAYONE

    OPEN(UNIT=20,FILE='testfile.txt',STATUS='OLD', ACTION='READ')
    READ (20,*) ARRAYONE
    print *, 'here I am!'
    CLOSE(UNIT=20)
    write(*,*)ARRAYONE
    OPEN(UNIT=30,FILE='TEXTFILE.txt', STATUS='REPLACE', ACTION='WRITE')
    WRITE(30,*)ARRAYONE
END PROGRAM test_performance
```

There is no error when I compile it. The point is that the array `ARRAYONE` as well as the file `TEXTFILE.txt` are empty.

The file `testfile.txt` Looks like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
```

I have got a book in front of me according to which this should actually work. What puzzles me is the fact that if I put just one number in the input file, i.e., 1, and I want to write it on an integer, there is no problem and everything works fine :o!

Comment: Of Course the book lies and I haven't misunderstood it :) Thanks a lot, it works perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the vainglorious pursuit of rep, and with the noble intention that this question get an answer

You can't automatically allocate an array in a `read` statement, the rules forbid it (or, if you prefer, do not make allowance for it).  You could either:

1. allocate the array to some size that you expect to be large enough, populate it with a guard value unlikely to be found in your inputs, and then read the data you have into the first `n` elements; or
2. read the data, figure out how many elements there are, allocate the array to that size, pass the data to the array;  you could do this in two passes over the input file (one to determine the contents, the second to read it) or you could get clever and read the data into, say, a large string and parse it to find out how many numbers it contains (so simple it's scarcely worthy of the name 'parsing').

There are other ways, I'm sure you can think of some.